# local ports range redirection to corresponding addresses range using iptables

Tags: linux, networking, iptables, linux-networking

So i have this linux router, that has 2000 differents ips.
And i want to redirect local source ports between 10001 and 12000 linearly from source addresses in the subnet 192.168.0.0/21

So that would means,

localhost:10001 has the source address 192.168.0.1
localhost:10002 ==> 192.168.0.2
...
localhost:10256 ==> 192.168.1.1
...
etc

I know how to do that with 2000 lines of iptables, like this :

iptables -A POSTROUTING -t nat -p tcp --sport 10001 -j SNAT --to-source 192.168.0.1
...
...

But what i'm after is avoiding doing 2000 lines of iptables and use port range/address range of iptables or somekind of trick that could be possible.

Anyone ?

Many thanks

Answer (score 0):

Mmmm... I don't think so. You *will* need 2000 rules. Although you don't have to do them all manually.